# Ansible how to get value from dictionary using a mix of variable and string as key

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

Im trying to achieve something like that , being easier saying than implementing, basically I want to get value from dictionary using a mix of variable and string as key at an import_task, so the code should be something like that :

```
- import_tasks: "somefile_{{ somedic[ansible_distribution'_'ansible_distribution_major_version ] }}.yml"
```

The dic should be something like that :

```
somedic: { "RedHat_7": "endoffilename" }
```

And when run on a server RedHat 7 it should end loading a file called

```
somefile_endoffilename.yml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with that dictionary structure, because it requires nested variable dereferencing, which Jinja2 does not support.  So your dictionary needs to look like this:

```
vars:
  somedic:
    "RedHat":
       "7": "endoffilename"
```

In JSON, that looks like:

```
vars:
  somedic: { "RedHat": { "7": "endoffilename" } }
```

Then, you can get what you need:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    somedic: { "RedHat": { "7": "endoffilename" } }

    OS: RedHat
    MajorVersion: "7"

  tasks:
   - debug:
      msg: "somefile_{{ somedic[OS][MajorVersion] }}.yml"
```

The output of the `debug` task is:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************
Tuesday 26 May 2020  11:14:30 -0400 (0:00:00.027)       0:00:00.146 *********** 
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "somefile_endoffilename.yml"
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks, so what I cannot demand a key from a dic using a mix of variable and string ?

Comment: No.  Cannot nest variable dereferences.

Comment: its not nested, its one level dic, the line somedic: { "RedHat_7": "endoffilename" } means that its a dic named somedic with just one key value pair

Comment: I know.  And if you actually had the key as one variable, it would not be a problem.  But you don't.  Your key is made up of two variables, which cannot be combined to make one.  So you need to restructure your dictionary to use two keys.

Comment: Its ok, what a curious limitation